# Set up an actitivity that will blocked until a new element insert into my database

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm new in workflows C #, I want to set up an activity that will be blocked until a new element insert into my database , after I pass to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I believe you are asking for a way to stop the workflow proceeding until you get a database entry and if you do to continue the workflow.
And if you do not get the entry to not continue the workflow.

This answer uses the Flowchart model of workflows.

A way to do this is to write an Code Activity (also called Custom Activity) that reads your database and determines if the entry has arrived and then sets a bool Out Argument of the activity.  This bool should set a Variable in the workflow.
Then after that you add a FlowDecision activity to read the bool Variable. 
If true you continue the workflow
If false you add a loop back to your database reading activity.

This solution leaves the workflow running in memory.
There are more sophisticated solutions but as you are new to workflows I have given the most simple.

Comment: Thank you richard, I have already developed a solution using CodeActivity  but there is a problem when I changed the value of OutArgument <String> Outside The method execute, I have the following exception:
ActivityContext is not accessible within the scope of the function in which it was passed.
Thank you again

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying.
Are you getting this exception when changing the Argument inside the Activity or inside the workflow scope?
Please edit your post and the add the code you are referring to.

Comment: when i changed the arqument outside the method execute.

Comment: So your Delegate is not getting the context.
i'm sorry I do not know why this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public sealed class Controller: CodeActivity
{
    public  OutArgument<String> Item { get; set; }


    CodeActivityContext con; 
    public  SqlTableDependency<VacationRequest> _dependency;

    private void _dependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<VacationRequest> even)

    {
        if (even.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)

        {
            switch (even.ChangeType)

            {
                case ChangeType.Update:
                    try
                    {
                       Item.Set(con, "yeééés");// ****Exception
                        Console.WriteLine("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                        //_dependency.Stop();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        con.SetValue(Item, "tttt");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

       con = context;
        _dependency = new SqlTableDependency<VacationRequest>(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbContext"].ConnectionString, "VacationRequests");

            _dependency.OnChanged += _dependency_OnChanged;

        _dependency.Start();

        //context.SetValue(Item, "test");
    }
}
```